# "Would be most welcomed and appreciated" or "most welcome and appreciated"

Tags: idiomatic-language

> 1. Comments are most welcomed and appreciated.
> 2. Comments are most welcome and appreciated.

Which one is more idiomatic? And also, it should be "most" or mostly"?

Comment: Both are OK, in my opinion. However, not mostly, since that changes the meaning: mostly would mean not completely welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I'd go with #2 and perhaps change the word order: "Comments are welcome and most appreciated."

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker from the US, I find #2 the most idiomatically correct.

I disagree with the commenter who said that you should change the word order to "Comments are welcome and most appreciated." That sounds fine too, but I personally think your version sounds more normal.

You have it right--it should be "most," not "mostly." (If you said "mostly," it would mean that comments are "mostly appreciated," as in, you don't appreciate all of them.)